# is there a tidy way to adhere to 'strict' and 'warnings' parameters when constructing "until (EXPR) BLOCK" statements in perl?

Tags: perl, loops

Using the following code as a reference...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $counter = 0;
until ($counter == 10){
    $counter++;
}
print $counter;
```

..by doing this, the $counter variable is accessible outside the until loop, thus running this will print "10".

However, it's been nagging me.. **How can I declare the $counter varible, in adherence with 'use warnings' (and possibly strict?), but only have it accesible within the until loop.**

Whilst I'm not expert.. having coded in perl for a few years now, instinctively the following should work...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

until (my $counter == 10){
    $counter++;
}
```

but it seems that by not first declaring $counter as a numerical value, and because we're using a == in the expression, the following warning is printed..

```
Use of uninitialized value $counter in numeric eq (==) at test.pl line 5.
```

I know it might seem anal. But I must satisfy the hunch I'm getting..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [C-style for loop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops):

```
for ( my $counter = 0; $counter != 10; $counter++ ) {
    ...;
}
```

Or better yet, [a counting loop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops):

```
for my $counter ( 0 .. 9 ) {
    ...;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, and it makes total sense. As per the 'perlsyn' document, it clearly states that by declaring the variable it will lexically scope it.
However, I focused on the 'until', as it allowed me the flexibility of using a >= expression.

maybe its just late, but I can't seem to work that same sort of expression into your examples.

I dont suppose you wouldnt mind expanding on the above to incorperate a >= expression, please?

Comment: @BIGMOOSE, a "C-style for loop" is really a while loop in disguise. `INIT; until (EXIT_COND) BLOCK` is the same as `for (INIT; !EXIT_COND; ) BLOCK`.

Comment: I get it.. accordingly to allow me to do a `until ($x > $y){...}` or `while ($x < $y){...}` loop i would do a c-style for loop like.. `for (my $x = 0; $x < $y; $x++){...}`

Comment: @BIGMOOSE Of course, saving a single line of code isn't a great justification for switching to a C-style loop (it's usually not a great justification for anything). In general, try to write readable, maintainable code instead of worrying about an extra line or two here and there. Avoid C-style loops if they can easily be written in a more readable fashion (like Miller's second example).